# Getting error while connecting to remote SQL Server from PowerShell with domain account

Tags: powershell, remote-connections

I am getting an error while connecting to a remote SQL Server from PowerShell with a domain account. I have admin rights to the system.

This is my script:

```
$SQLServer = "testsql"
$SQLDBName = "SQLInfo"
$uid ="FAREAST\testuser"
$ConnectionString="Server = $SQLServer; Database = $SQLDBName"
$pwd = "testpwd"
$dpwd = ConvertTo-SecureString -String $pwd -AsPlainText -Force
$dpwd.MakeReadOnly() 
$creds = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCredential ($uid,$dpwd)
$con = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
$con.ConnectionString = $ConnectionString
$con.Credential = $creds
$con.Open() 
$SqlCmd = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
$SqlCmd.CommandText = $SqlQuery
$SqlCmd.Connection = $con
$SqlAdapter = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter
$SqlAdapter.SelectCommand = $SqlCmd
$DataSet = New-Object System.Data.DataSet
$SqlAdapter.Fill($DataSet)
$DataSet.Tables[0] | out-file "D:\Eswar\data.txt"
```

I get the following error message:

> Exception calling "Open" with "0" argument(s): "Login failed for user 'FAREAST\testUser'."
>   At line:12 char:2
>   +  $con.Open()
>   +  ~~~~~~~~~~~
>   + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
>   + FullyQualifiedErrorId : SqlException

Comment: If I add trusted_connection=yes/Integrated Security=yes/SSPI it will ignore the credentials and login with current user account. I don't want to login with current user account

Comment: Please help me on this. Thanks in advance.